# What goes in the "Non-Public members" node in Visual Studio's Watch window?

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-debugging, vsx

I assumed that all Non-Public (ie, private, protected, internal, and internal protected) members of C# objects go under "*Non-Public Members*" when I look at objects in Visual Studio's Watch Window. But then, I noticed an anamoly with this code:

```
   class HashDerived : System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm { ... }

   HashAlgorithm hash1 = new HashDerived();
   HashAlgorithm hash2 = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Cng();
```

`hash1`'s "Non-Public Members" looks like this:

[image: hash1 in Watch Window]

whereas `hash2`'s "Non-Public Members" looks like this:

[image: hash2 in Watch Window]

So it seems like for hash1, only the `private` field (m_bDisposed) appears under the "*Non-Public members*" node, where for hash2, even `protected` and `protected internal` members like "HashSizeValue" and "HashValue" appear in it.

Why does this happen? What are the rules behind this behaviour?

Comment: SHA1Cng is declared **sealed**.  So its protected members are no longer accessible by any derived class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing here is a bug.  The C# debugger shouldn't be showing static members in this scenario.  I confirmed this with the current owner of the code base and he's going to file a bug for the next release of Visual Studio.

The specific scenario under which this happens is

- Just My Code is enabled
- The type is defined in what's determined to be a non-user assembly
- The type of the reference and object instance are different (switch `hash2` to `SHA1Cnf` and the problem disappears)

Note there may be other scenarios where this appears.  This is the behavior I was able to narrow down in the debugging / experimentation that I did.